# TM1 vba library files

Tags: excel, cognos-tm1, vba

I have just upgraded excel version from 2003 to 2016. I'm facing prob for the statement
Application.Run ("TM1RECALC1")

And the below library files shows missing in the references window
"MISSINg:ResQ3 Automation Library"
"MISSINg:ResQ ActiveX model Automation DLL"
"Missing: RESQ data Object ActiveX dll (ResQData)"
How do I remove these errors.

regards,
Anna

Comment: can any one please help on this one....ITS URGENT

Comment: Do you have the ResQ application installed and the add-in loaded?

Comment: What are the addins that I should load to remove these erros.ca you please help me on this one

Comment: Hello Rory, Could you please tell me which are the application I should download. I know very little on TM1

Comment: You need the ResQ reserving application.

Comment: Rory, Which version of ResQ reserving application works fine with Office 16/Office 365. I have hundreds of files to upgrade. Thank you

Comment: I have no idea - I haven't used ResQ in a long time. You should ask its developers.